# Is there a way to create a software box's background shadow using CSS?

Tags: css, background, shadow

Imagine a software box like the following:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sitellite.org](http://www.sitellite.org/pix/sitellite-box.gif))</sub>

Now imagine the shadow is not there. Is there a CSS way that I can simulate that background shadow, and work on at least Firefox and Chrome, if not also IE9 and up?

Comment: Use a transformed gradient. (That means, use `transform: skew(...)` and `background-image: linear-gradient(...)`.)

Comment: Maybe with CSS3 transformations..

Comment: You're using an image for the box, so why not an image for the shadow too?

Comment: @enhzflep This is because I'm adding this to a WordPress theme, and I want someone to upload just the box and I'll place it on a blue background for them and add shadow with code on the fly. I didn't want them to have to worry about the shadow. However, my code could worry about it and use an image behind the image, yes.

Comment: @Volomike - ahah.. Gotcha. I'd probably be inclined to look into generating the shadow image on the fly. Using a canvas and some javascript in much the same way would usually use <insert image editing suite of choice>. Of course, this would fail on some browsers, as would css3 transforms. For the best compatibility, I'd use an image + js. For the best look, I'd use a canvas to generate the image before chucking it onto the page. I'm inclined to think that css transforms would calculate the shadow incorrectly (top right of box for example) also, canvas would allow a faux-perspective effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to start with a triangle shape like this

```
<div id="triangle"></div>

#triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid grey;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    opacity:0.1;
}​
```

[see example](http://jsfiddle.net/X7Svy/)

Then add a linear-gradient and position it behind the image. Take a look at this [gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) as a starting point.

Then you could use [transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) to skew it slightly.